# Сервер linux завис при установке Jira

Tags: jira

при установке Jira выбрал простой вариант с установкой через атласиан

и получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как понимаю сервер зарылся (мало памяти\ядер)

подключение по winscp сбрасывает.

как быть в такой ситуации? putty наглухо повисла

Comment: Jira никогда не славилась скоростью работы. Вполне вероятно, что она загрузила Ваш сервер по полной (к примеру, это мог сделать java'вский GC).  Если страницу закрыть, то максимум плохого, что произойдет - это просто не установиться jira.

Я бы немного подождал (пол часика) и попробовал обновить страницу. Если ничего не поменяется - перезугрузить сервер и посмотреть, что там случилось. Скорее всего просто кончилось место на диске.

Comment: вполне возможно не хватает проца. ждал больше получаса. думаю серв повис. если не отвиснет то ребутить по ssh?

Comment: если Вы не можете зайти по winscp, то по ssh скорее всего не зайдете. Если получится все же, запустите top и посмотрите, кто выжирает проц. Тажке запустите `df -h` и посмотрите, осталось ли место на диске. Тяжелые задачи можно прибить с помощью kill.